# Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined but IS defined in an included js file

Tags: php, jquery

Ok, I've searched google and all over this site and am not finding the solution.

I have a php file with a button. I have all the included bootstrap/jquery-ui css files at the top and the corresponding .js files at the bottom. I also have a custom .js file that has ONE function which defines a custom dialog box. When I try to call it from the php file I get:

> ReferenceError: $myDialog is not defined.

The included js file is called `dialog.js` and IS in the `js` folder.

Here are the php and js files:

```js
$(function() {
    
    /**
     * $myDialog Custom Dialog Function
     * 
     * Example Usage:
     *  var theTitle = "CUSTOM TITLE GOES HERE!";
  * var msg = 'Your message goes here...';
  * $myDialog.dialog("option", "title", theTitle);
  * $myDialog.html(msg + '</div>');
  * $myDialog.dialog('open');
     *
     * Filename: dialog.js
     **/

    var $myDialog = $('<div id="dialog-message">')
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'center'],
        width: 400,
        
        dialogClass: 'dialog-message ui-dialog-osx',
        title: "Important Message!",
        autoOpen: false,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ],        
    });

});
```

```html
<?php
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
  <title>Rental Application</title>
  <!-- CSS Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/html5reset.css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/drwebguy.css" media="all" />
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="home" class="container-fluid main_content">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><a id="btnMyDialog" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">myDialog</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>This is just some text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- class="container-fluid" -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.cookie.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/drwebguy.js">--></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    
    $('#btnMyDialog').on('click', function(){
     var theTitle = "CUSTOM TITLE GOES HERE!";
     var msg = 'Your message goes here...';
     $myDialog.dialog("option", "title", theTitle);
     $myDialog.html(msg + '</div>');
     $myDialog.dialog('open');
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And, obviously, if I put that var function at the bottom of my file instead of including an external js file it works fine...but, also obviously, that defeats the purpose of oop :/

Answer (score 0):

use all script like this :

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function(){    
      // .. script what you want
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Fky, I'll give that a go.